# Database Normalization Validation

Tags: normalization

How do I know if I normalized correctly to 2NF or 3NF? I am still struggling how to validate, that I followed the algorithm correctly.
[image]

Is this a normlization that would correspond to 3NF? I an a little bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data schema you have these rules:

At an `Incident` there can be **MANY** `Responders`.

A `Responder` can have **ONE** `Device`.

A `Responder` can have **ONE** `res_latitude` and **ONE** `res_longitude`.

A `Device` can have **ONE** `Dev_installation`.

If the above are what you want then i think it's ok (but see again the primary keys).

Also, i forgot to mention that the reason of keeping the `responder_id` and `device_id` in a separate table is to keep historical data in case `device_id` change `responder_id`. You could also merge `ResponceIncidentDevice` in one table with keys `incident_id, responder_id, device_id` so you will be able to know in what incidents a reponder went carrying what devices.

EDIT:

According to your comment you need to make the following changes. Also note that it is better to use lower case for all your tables and columns to avoid case sensitivity problems due to various engine implemantations.

```
Responders
responder_id    res_latitude    res_longitude

Responders_Devices (pk: responder_id, device_id)
responder_id    device_id
1               1
1               2
2               3
2               4
3               5
```

Comment: It is almost what i was aiming for. I want a `Responder` can have **MANY** `Device`

Comment: Do you want a Responder to have many devices and each device can belong to many Responders or at only one?

Comment: A responder can have many devices and each device belongs to one responder

Comment: When do I need to use Intersection Tables and when does it make sense to use a combined PK in one table?

Comment: If you have a NxM relation then you need a table that it's (candidate) primary key will be table_one_primary_key, table_two_primary_key

Comment: I changed the diagram in the question. Now I use Intersection Tables. Would that be the way to go then? Aren't intersection tables complicating more the statements for querying needed?

Comment: It's the only way. Don't be afraid of JOIN's. This is why the 'R' is at RDBMS (Relational).

Comment: If ONE responder can have MANY devices, is this a NxM relation? Because one device can only have one responder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94501/discussion-between-sesc360-and-kostas-mitsarakis).

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are a lot many tutorials available on the subject but they are a little complex, I can understand your problem.

First of all your project isn't even legal for First Normalization form because your second table, RespondersIncidents, is a table which has two foreign keys but you have no primary keys.

Now let me simplify the rules for you.

1NF - You must have a primary key (One sentence layman definition)
2NF - No Partial Dependency, Try not to have two entries in one column and make sure that your primary key uniquely identifies the whole row. 
3NF - No Functional Dependency, Make sure that in one row only your specific primary key has the power to identify the whole row. For e.g. if in one row there is primary key (auto generated) and student id as well which is unique then we have functional dependency here that means we don't need a separate primary key, we can use student id as primary key.

I hope this was informative for you. I kept it short and simple.

Comment: Thank you. I read a lot of these tutorials and I think i understood the concept, still i do not know how to validate my results. The ResponderIncidents table should link between the tables.

Comment: You Second Table has two columns and both of them are Foreign Keys right? You can do this, you can attach them in one and use them as primary key. You are good for 1 NF then. Except that you are good to go. Normalization is a process. In college we used to make DFD first and then worked on Normalization step by step. At times you can decide to go with non-normalized from if that helps your execution time.

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php                       Check this